# How to wait in the same thread while file is being written to, to finish, so we can use it

Tags: java, android

I have a file open and write situation that crashes with EOFException once in about 20-30 times, because the file is unavailable because some other process is writing to it.

Can I catch this exception, then somehow wait for the file write operation synchronously to end, so I can recurse the method?

```
File productJSON = getFileStreamPath("product" + "_" + getId() + ".json");
if (!productJSON.exists()) {
    productJSON = getFileStreamPath("product" + ".json");
}

InputStream jsonStringsFileInputStream;
try {
    jsonStringsFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(productJSON);

    HashMap<String, Map> that = new JSONToProductParser().convertThisToThat(jsonStringsFileInputStream);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: not able to understand your Question can you please ellobrate

Comment: read/write operations on a file should be synchronized to avoid concurrency on a multithread app

Comment: Mark the File as synchronized. It will solve your problem in that case only one thread at a time will able to write on it.

Comment: how do I mark the file as synchronized? wherever Im writing to it or wherever Im reading from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the file for write access before opening it.This is done with the **canWrite()** method.

[Oracle Docs - File # canWrite](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29)

Also check out this solved question. It deals with the synchronized attribute.

[Solved Question - Synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592409/do-i-need-to-implement-synchronized-on-writing-data-to-a-same-file-by-using-buff)

Comment: So what do I do if canWrite returns false? do I keep looping the check?
So do I make all the methods that deal with this file synchronized?

Comment: You can poll for a certain time or amount of tries,if it doesnt change its status throw an exception or handle it according to you needs.Regarding synchronization you might wanna read into this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use a handler to introduce delays in your code.

```
final Handler handler=new Handler();
handler.postdelayed(new Runnable(){
@override
public void run(){
//Do something after 5 seconds....your code here
     }
},5000);
```

write your code within the run method

Comment: This didnt work, because when I call the same method from within the handler, the rest of the code that started this method doesnt wait for the second iteration but goes on instead